# At what point is the following Python socket-level-programming code stuck?

Tags: python-3.x, sockets

This is the server.py file which runs a basic server:

```
import socket
import sys

sockett = socket.socket()
sockett.bind(('127.0.0.1', 123))
sockett.listen(10)
while True:
    print('1', end='')
    while True:
        print('2', end='')
        try:
            client, addr = sockett.accept()
            print(client,addr)
            break
        except Exception as e:
            print(e)
    print(client.recv(400))
    print(client.recv(1024))
    print('3')
print('4')
```

And this is the client.py code that I am running:

```
import socket
import sys

sockett = socket.socket()
sockett.connect(('127.0.0.1', 123))
sockett.send(b'0')
print("Hello")
```

The doubt I have is that when I run the server.py (let S) file and then the client.py (let C) file, S keeps on running but C stops running which should be the case but the point at which S is stuck is the main problem. It prints 3 for the first time and then does not print anything, not 4 (so not out of the loop) not 1 (so not still looping). What could the reason be? Where is the code after it has printed 3?
This is the output I am getting:

```
12<socket......>(...)
b'0'
b''
3
_ (keeps on running indefinitely)
```

According to me, it should print 1 first, then 2, then run into an error which would be handled by try-except, and then print:

```
b''
b''
3
```

and then keep on looping like this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The server is actually looping, but the reason you don't see the 1 or 2  when you're running this script is because you're not flushing your output:

```
import socket
import sys

sockett = socket.socket()
sockett.bind(('127.0.0.1', 123))
sockett.listen(10)
while True:
    print('1', end='')
    while True:
        print('2', end='', flush=True)
        try:
            client, addr = sockett.accept()
            print(client,addr)
            break
        except Exception as e:
            print(e)
    print(client.recv(400))
    print(client.recv(1024))
    print('3')
print('4')
```

You'll notice that with `flush=True`, in `print('2', end='', flush=True)` you'll see the `12` appear prior to the client's connection, and once again after the client disconnects.

> ```
> 12<socket...> (...)
> b'0'
> b''
> 3
> 12_ (keeps on running indefinitely)
> ```

With this, you can see that it's waiting again at `client, addr = sockett.accept()`

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I understand it all but what exactly does flush do and why is there a difference when we use it and when we don't use it? What does it mean to flush the output?

Comment: @TanishJain [This page](https://eklitzke.org/stdout-buffering) will explain a lot. The really short version is that it helps with program speed when there's a lot of output happening.

Comment: Thanks for all your help, I now understand it all.

P.S. Sorry for the late reply.

Answer (score 0):

```
while True:
    print('1', end='')
    while True:
        print('2', end='')
        try:
            client, addr = sockett.accept()
            print(client,addr)
            break
        except Exception as e:
            print(e)
```

This part will succeed (and not run into an error as you assume) once the client has connected.

```
    print(client.recv(400))
```

This will read the `b'0'` send by the client.

```
    print(client.recv(1024))
    print('3')
```

This will wait for more data. Since the client closes the connection it will return with `''`, i.e. no data.

Then it will go to the beginning of the loop and from there into the inner loop where it is calling `accept` again. `accept` will block until it gets a new connection. Since you don't run the client again `accept` will block forever.

Comment: Your answer is incomplete. Read the question again, please. The answer you wrote is what I am expecting to happen but it does not happen like that and @Ruzihm has already given the right answer for that.

Comment: @TanishJain: You might consider it incomplete since it not addresses that you fail to see some output as the other answer dows. It explains though why and where your program seems to be stuck (hangs in accept) - which is exactly what you ask in the title of your question.